# GDAL: gdalwarp wrong transformation to "South_Pole_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area" EPSG:102020

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to reproject a raster that is defined in EPSG:4326 to EPSG:102020.

Command used

```
gdalwarp -ot Float32 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:102020 -r near -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 etopo1.tif etopo1_warped_cli.tif
```

but the output has a wrong coordinate reference system, as it is shown as

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

instead of

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

On the other hand if I manually specify the parameters for the target srs then transformation is ok and the raster is recognized as EPSG:102020 in Desktop GIS software:

```
gdalwarp -ot Float32 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -r near -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 etopo1.tif etopo1_warped_cli.tif
```

NOTE: 
the above is on Windows, because on Linux the operation returns

```
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 102020 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
EPSG:102020
```

Comment: 102020 is an Esri projected CRS, not an EPSG one. It may not be defined in the PROJ4 tables.

Comment: @mkennedy thanks! is there any EPSG equivalent?

Comment: I'm sorry about the delay in answering. I couldn't find anything. Nothing at all using Lambert azimuthal equal-area in Antarctica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, 102020 is not an EPSG code, but an ESRI one.

So the safe solution is to use

```
gdalwarp -ot Float32 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -r near -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 etopo1.tif etopo1_warped_cli.tif
```

In Desktop GIS like QGIS a custom CRS can be created (with any name, the internal code will be auto-generated) with this definition

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

and then use this instead of the default one (code 102020).